# Different radius of convergence for ratio test and Hadamard's formula

Tags: complex-analysis, convergence-divergence

I'm pretty sure I'm missing something very basic... But I have the following question:

Determine the radius of convergence of $\sum \alpha_n z^n$ with $\alpha_n=\frac{1}{n+1}$.

Now, with the ratio test this gives $R=1$. But with Hadamard's formula we get $1/R = \lim\sup |\alpha_n|^{1/n} =\lim\sup\sqrt[n]{\frac{1}{n+1}}=0$, implying that $R=\infty$.

What am I missing/doing wrong?

Comment: Are you sure that the limit is equal to $0$?

Comment: As $n$ increases, $n^{(1/n)} \to 1.$

Comment: Oh god...of course. I kept treating it like $\sqrt[2]{1/n}$... I need more coffee.